# Phone turn on while charging

Tags: power-on, 7.1-nougat

I have a Lenovo K8 Note. Yesterday I put my phone on charging when it was on 2% and I slept. When I woke up my battery was 100% but my phone was off. I don't know what could have caused it. My phone is new and my charger works fine.
Moreover, is there any feature that turns the phone on when it is put to charging or if the phone turns 100. Something like that?

Comment: Same happened with Google Nexus 5x, after checking, there is pending update, which download but cannot installed to battery low, when i plug charger and sleep, phone try auto installed and go for restart, but unable to start auto after shutdown. So, may be you need to check update log/history...

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no such "feature". Maybe there was a power outage? Maybe it's a bug? If it happens again, contact Lenovo and send the phone in under warranty...

Btw, it wears down the battery quickly if you fully discharge it regularly. (https://lifehacker.com/5875162/how-often-should-i-charge-my-gadgets-battery-to-prolong-its-lifespan)